# Calculating difference in multi index pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`:

```
df_test = sns.load_dataset("flights")
df_test['cat_2'] = np.random.choice(range(10), df_test.shape[0])
df_test.pivot_table(index='month', 
                      columns='year', 
                      values=['passengers', 'cat_2'])\
                          .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)\
                          .sort_index(axis=1, level=0)\
                          .fillna(0)
```

I am trying to calculate the difference between `cat_2` and `passengers` each `year` compared to the year before.

What is the best way to achieve this?
Desired output would look similar to this:

```
year    1949                            1950                                1951    
        cat_2   passengers    % diff    cat_2   passengers   % diff         cat_2   passengers     % diff
month                                                                                   
Jan     6       112           0         6       115          115/112        6       90                90/115
Feb     0       118           0         6       126          126/118        6       150               150 / 126  
Mar     2       132           0         7       141                         7       141
Apr     0       129           0         9       135                         9       135
May     5       121           0         4       125                         4       125
Jun     1       135           0         3       149                         3       149
Jul     6       148           0         5       170                         5       170
Aug     5       148           0         2       170                         2       170
Sep     1       136           0         4       158                         4       158
Oct     5       119           0         5       133                         5       133
Nov     0       104           0         1       114                         1       114
Dec     7       118           0         1       140                         1       140
```

I only showed the desired calculations for columns `passengers` but the same calculations method can be used for `cat_2` as well.
As there is nothing to compare the first year I filled the values with `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select columns `passengers` by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), divide by shifted rows by [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), create `MultiIndex` and append to original `DataFrame`:

```
df_test = sns.load_dataset("flights")
df_test['cat_2'] = np.random.choice(range(10), df_test.shape[0])
df = df_test.pivot_table(index='month', 
                      columns='year', 
                      values=['passengers', 'cat_2'])\
                          .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)\
                          .sort_index(axis=1, level=0)\
                          .fillna(0)
                          
                          
df1 = df.xs('passengers', axis=1, level=1)

df2 = pd.concat({'% diff': df1.div(df1.shift(axis=1)).fillna(0)}, axis=1)

out = (pd.concat([df, df2.swaplevel(axis=1)], axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=0, sort_remaining=False))
```

Another idea is shift values by add `1` year, only necessary remove last `NaN` column by `iloc`:

```
df1 = df.xs('passengers', axis=1, level=1)

df2 = (pd.concat({'% diff': df1.div(df1.rename(columns=lambda x: x+1))}, axis=1)
         .fillna(0)
         .iloc[:, :-1])

out = (pd.concat([df, df2.swaplevel(axis=1)], axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=0, sort_remaining=False))
```

Comment: Thank you, how could I `sort` the rows by `cat_2` of the `latest` `year?`

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - Use `df.sort_values([(df.columns.levels[0].max(),'cat_2')])`